# Is からすると contraction of から判断すると?

Tags: words

Is からすると contraction of から判断すると?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1916/5010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think ～からすると is a contraction of nothing; it is a set phrase by itself. But meaning-wise, yes it means either ～から判断すると ("judging from ～") or ～の観点から考えると ("from the standpoint of ～"). Here's an example of からすると which does *not* mean から判断すると:

> 彼からすると私は馬鹿だ。
>   From his point of view, I am an idiot. (rather than "Judging from him, ...")