# How is したら acting in this sentence: こいつからしたら当然の反応だが

Tags: meaning, conditionals

Can anyone help me find out what したら is doing in this sentence:

> くそ。こいつからしたら当然の反応だが

I assume こいつから to be "from these guys", 当然の反応 to be "natural response" and だが to be "but/however".

Now for the confusing part. The したら seems to be the たら conditional of する. Could this be "expressing surprise at the condition" like Tae Kim says [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals)?  Even so, how does する fit here? Could the speaker be saying something along the lines of "whatever these guys do, I'm not surprised (It's my natural reaction at this point)"?

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been coming across more uses of たら that don't necessarily translate to "if" or "when", so that can partly contribute to my uncertainty with this problem.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/is-there-a-difference-between-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65794/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means ”Shit. For him, it’s a natural response.”
But I can’t expect why there is “？”. You may understand the meaning by context.
からしたら means “for, in one’s opinion”

> 彼からしたら将棋よりもチェスの方が難しい。
>   For him, chess is more difficult than shogi.
>   僕からしたら数学で50点を取るのは凄いと思うよ。
>   In my opinion, it’s great to get 50 points in maths.

Comment: That question mark is for the question I asked. Not part of the sentence in question. My apologies. I could have written that better

Comment: Could you perhaps break down what everything his doing here? How are から and する (conditional) working together to mean "for him" or "in one's opinion"? In a literal context, it would be "from to do", more simply put "from doing". And of course the conditional たら is used. I would think it would mean something more closely along the lines of "From one's experience" or "Due to". Perhaps "from doing" gives that person their opinion or allows からしたら to be translated as "For x person" since that person has done the act (whatever this act may be).

Comment: OK! I understand the meaning of “?”. I was careless. This may not be grammatically correct but I’d like to tell you my opinion as a native Japanese speaker. “Xからしたら” literally means “If I did that from my position”. If you want to say “from my experience”, “私の経験から言えば” would suit. And “Xにしては” also has similar meaning, it is used like “considering”. For example. “君にしてはミスが多い試合だった。”, “50歳にしては足が速い。”. Anyway you are doing high-level study, I want you to master Japanese soon and enjoy Japanese songs, movies, mangas and manzais.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have miles to go still but I thank you for your time and kind words.