# Difference between からして and からすれば

Tags: grammar, nuances, jlpt

> 今のロンドンの成長率 _______ 、この先の二十年で彼の資産価値は十倍以上にふくらむだろう。
>
> a) からこそ
> b) からには
> c) からして
> d) からすれば

からすれば is the proper answer. According to a post I have found it seems to be used when judgment is based on the objective factors, and からして is more of an opinion than judgment. Is it correct reasoning? I assume 成長率 to be an objective data.

Comment: Possible duplicate, where からすれば and からすると are interchangeable: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/is-there-a-difference-between-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I believe からして, からすれば, からすると and からしたら are interchangeable, and c) and d) are both correct answers. You can actually find many examples of 成長率からして on the net. Maybe からして is relatively stiff and からしたら is relatively casual among the four.

Note that からして has other meanings ("starting with", "even from", "even") which is discussed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1133/5010). According to 明鏡国語辞典 第二版:

> #### からして
>
> ①起点の意味を強める。「子供の時分━頑固だった」
>
> ②後に続く判断の根拠を表す。…からみて。…からいって。「今の状況━成功は望めない」「彼の口ぶり━転職する気はなさそうだ」
>
> ③最も基本的なものを挙げ、他はましてと強める。…さえ（も）。…も。「着るもの━人とは違う」「こんな初歩的なこと━理解できない」